# How to merge data frames by column name that are separated by commas and/or dashes

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, separator

Given two data frames

data set1 "results"

```
 Gene     Test1 Test2 Test3  
    ABCD   0.12 0.56  00.43  
    DEFG   0.34 0.67  0.91   
    HIJK   0.34 0.33  0.56 
    LM,O-P 0.22 0.12  0.34   
    Q-R,ST 0.34 0.45  0.23
```

data set2 ="BP"

```
Gene  BP  Chr
ABCD  873  1
DEFG  874  1
HIJK  875  1
LM,O-P 876 1
Q-R,ST 877 1
```

Desired outcome

```
Gene  Test1 Test2 Test3 BP  Chr
ABCD   0.12 0.56  00.43  873  1
DEFG   0.34 0.67  0.91   874  1
HIJK   0.34 0.33  0.56   875  1
LM,O-P 0.22 0.12  0.34   876  1
Q-R,ST 0.34 0.45  0.23   877  1
```

But I get this instead when using the merge function

```
merge.data<-merge(results,BP, by.x="Gene",all.x=TRUE)
Gene  Test1 Test2 Test3 BP  Chr
ABCD   0.12 0.56  00.43  873  1
DEFG   0.34 0.67  0.91   874  1
HIJK   0.34 0.33  0.56   875  1
LM,O-P 0.22 0.12  0.34   NA  NA
Q-R,ST 0.34 0.45  0.23   NA  NA
```

It appear the merge function is not merging the Gene names that have commas and dashes in them. How can I merge them without removing the commas and dashes?

Comment: It is possible that the unmatched strings may contain white space. Please check the data. Use `dput` to share the data here so we can also take a look.

Comment: The LM rows have zero in one data frame and oh in another.

Comment: Make sure the values are really identical. In your example above, `results` has a line with `"O-P"`, with the letter "O". `BP`, in the similar row, has `"0-P"` with a numeral zero. I don't see a discrepancy between the `Q-R,ST` rows, but it may be there (maybe in spaces, as ycw suggests). Look at `unique(BP$Gene)` and `unique(results$Gene)` carefully.

Comment: Sorry I made the correction in the line with the "O-P"  in both data sets, ti's and Oh not Zero. Therefore, that's not the issue

Comment: what's wrong with your code? It should work just fine!

Comment: @Gregor Does both data sets need to be the same length?

Comment: No, the number of rows don't matter. Only that the values in the `Gene` column match exactly.

Comment: The code should run fine - do you get `TRUE` if you run `all(BP$Gene %in% results$Gene)`? If not, there's probably a subtle difference between those values in the two dataframes. It could also be useful seeing the if there are extra rows produced if you run `merge.data<-merge(results, BP, all.y=TRUE, all.x=TRUE)`

Comment: Can you run this piece of code before `merge()` and let us know how `merge.data` looks: `results$Gene <- gsub("\\s", "", results$Gene); BP$Gene <- gsub("\\s", "", BP$Gene)`? After this if the issue is still not resolved then please share `dput(results)` and `dput(BP)` as suggested by ycw.

Comment: @hodgenovice I got FALSE when I ran your code

Comment: @geneteics_diva This confirms that the `Gene` columns in `results` and `BP` are not the same (even though they look it). I'd advise following @Prem's comment - the first part of which will remove various forms of white space, and (failing that), the second part will tell us more about the structure of your data so we can try to see why R sees them as different, because we can't tell what the differences are from the output in your question alone.